# Why I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined while running an apps script on Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I've been trying to find where the cause of it here, but I just can't.

Basically, it should look for the row(s) win Form Responses 1 containing testNo equal to the one and set "Yes" to them...
It does that, but it keeps giving me this error in the Logs.

I think that because the formRepValues may come with an array containing an empty element, it may be causing this error...?

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const testSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Todays Tests v2");
  const row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  const col = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const emailSent = testSheet.getRange(row, 13, 1, 1).getValue();

  const formRespSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  const formRespRng = formRespSheet.getRange(2, 13, formRespSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2);
  const formRespValues = formRespRng.getValues();

  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == testSheet.getSheetName() &&
    row > 5 &&
    col == 14 &&
    emailSent != 'Yes') {
    const email = testSheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
    const name = testSheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
    const testNo = testSheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();

    for (var n = 0; formRespValues.length; n++) {
      if (formRespValues[n][1] == testNo) {
        formRespSheet.getRange('M' + (2 + n)).setValue('Yes');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you forgot to set a condition to stop your for loop: the expression formRespValues.length will cause the for loop to run indefinitely.

Try the following:

```
for (var n = 0; n < formRespValues.length; n++) {
     if (formRespValues[n][1] == testNo) {
       formRespSheet.getRange('M' + (2 + n)).setValue('Yes');
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Some days without looking at it and the syntax starts fading away!

Comment: Happens to the best of us my friend! One way to not have to deal with this is to use the forEach() method with a callback function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

For your code, it would translate to :

```
formRespValues.forEach( (value, n) => {
if(value[1] == testNo) {
       formRespSheet.getRange('M' + (2 + n)).setValue('Yes');
     }
});
```